# Create new column with percentages in data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataframe:

```
dput(df1)

structure(list(month = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4), transaction_type = c("AAA", 
"BBB", "BBB", "CCC", 
"DDD", "AAA"), max_wt_per_month = c(54.9, 
51.6833333333333, 52.3333333333333, 49.4666666666667, 49.85, 
48.5833333333333), min_wt_per_month = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), avg_wt_per_month = c(8.41701333107861, 
7.65211141060198, 6.44184012508551, 7.74798927613941, 7.4360566888844, 
7.50611319574734), prop = c(Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf)), .Names = c("month", 
"transaction_type", "max_wt_per_month", "min_wt_per_month", "avg_wt_per_month", 
"prop"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), vars = list(month), drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    0:5), group_sizes = 6L, biggest_group_size = 6L, labels = structure(list(
    month = 1), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame", vars = list(
    month), drop = TRUE, .Names = "month"))
```

I want to create column `prop` that would contain the percentage of maximum waiting time with respect to each month. If I run this code, then I get `Inf` values in most of the rows... (especially it is evident in the real dataset):

```
my_fun=function(vec){ 
  100*as.numeric(vec[3]) / 
    sum(with(data_merged_transactions, ifelse(month == vec[1], max_wt_per_month, 0))) }
data_merged_transactions$prop=apply(data_merged_transactions , 1 , my_fun)
```

I then finally need to create the filled area chart so that each area would be a percentage out of 100%:

```
ggplot(data_merged_transactions, aes(x=month, y=prop, fill=transaction_type)) + 
  geom_area(alpha=0.6 , size=1, colour="black")
```

Why do I get `Inf` if the sum is not equal to 0?
Moreover, is it possible to create filled area chart with months being factors (Jan, Feb,etc.), not numbers? I tried to substitute month id's by month names, but then I got very thin bars instead of a filled area.

Comment: Can you give us the dput output of the original data frame? I'm struggling to import the one you've posted? Also can you elaborate what the 'percentage of maximum waiting time with respect to each month' is as a function of the other variables in the dataset?

Comment: @biomiha: The real dataset is large. I just posted `dput(head(df))`. The % on max waiting time means `MAX_WT[AAA,january]/SUM(MAX_WT[january])`, where max_wt is the 3rd column and AAA is the transaction_type of particular row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
library(tidyverse)
df1_tidy <- df1 %>% 
                group_by(month) %>% 
                summarise(SUM = sum(max_wt_per_month)) %>%
                full_join(df1) %>% 
                mutate(prop = max_wt_per_month / SUM)


ggplot(data = df1_tidy, 
       aes(x = month, 
           y = prop, 
           fill = transaction_type)) + 
  geom_area(alpha = 0.6, 
            size = 1, 
            colour = "black") +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr"))
```

Comment: Yes,right! Thank you very much! With the full data set it looks nice. Could you please answer the other sub-question related to the numbering of months (X axis). Is it possible to show month names instead of indices? If it's impossible, then how can I show all months like 1,2,3..12, but not 2.5, 5, 7.5 as it does now?

Comment: I think just relabelling the axis is the quickest / easiest. I've edited my answer by adding the `scale_x_continuous(labels = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr"))` to adjust for that. Now, obviously in the example dataset you've only got 4 months so if your entire dataset includes all 12, add them all to the labels vector.

Comment: It gives an error `Error in f(..., self = self) : Breaks and labels are different lengths`. I checked that `df1_tidy` contains the data for 12 months, and I putted 12 month names in `c("Jan","Feb",...)`. Do you knwo why does it happen? It looks like I should also define the number of breaks.

Comment: I tried to define the number of breaks `scale_x_continuous(breaks=12,by=1,...)`, but still the same error.

Comment: The breaks and labels vectors should be of the same length and I wouldn't really change the breaks parameter if I were you since it thinks it's a got an integer variable. My df1_tidy has only got 4 months and the code I pasted works fine.